# Modal content grows but the container size stays the same

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am displaying my modal with angularjs and here is the template:

```
<div class="modal-lg" modal="showModal" close="cancel()">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4>Cihaz Listesi - {{deviceCount}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 table-responsive">
                <table st-table="devices" st-safe-src="displayedDevices" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">

                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>IMEI-1</th>
                            <th>IMEI-2</th>
                            <th>MSISDN</th>
                            <th>Yeni IMEI-1</th>
                            <th>Yeni IMEI-2</th>
                            <th>Durum</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <tr data-ng-repeat="device in devices"  ng-click="selectRow(device.ItsRepairImeiListId)" st-select-row="device" st-select-mode="multi">
                            <td>{{device.Imei1}}</td>
                            <td>{{device.Imei2}}</td>
                            <td>{{device.Msisdn}}</td>
                            <td>{{device.NewImei1}}</td>
                            <td>{{device.NewImei2}}</td>
                            <td>{{device.Status.StatusDescription}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="text-center" st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="10" colspan="7"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button ng-show="selectedRows.length > 0" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="activateSelected()">Aktif Et</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">Kapat</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

`class="modal-lg"` is supposed to make the modal larger but here is what it looks like after using it:

[image]

What should I do to make both the content the container grow together ?

Comment: Whats is the positioning on model-body? is it fixed? Should be absolute, with model-lg fixed. Still would cause overflow.I just started working with  bootstrap 3 and angular UI. Had to write some custom classes to get things to work correctly. Also whats the overflow property?

Comment: One thing i notice that i did different was use the modal-content wrapper class above the modal-body.

Comment: Is the provided markup the complete markup for your modal? As there appears to be some missing or miss-placed DIVs that are a part of the modal markup for Bootstrap.

Comment: <div class="modal-lg"> <div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-body"> Was the class wrapping format i used with bootstrap 3

Comment: You should expect a horizontal scroll bar if you get everything working properly. The `.modal-lg` class maxes out at 900px for viewports 992px and larger. It looks like the screen you're on might be a bit smaller than that, hard to tell. If it is, `.modal-lg` is set to a width of 600px between viewports of 768px and 991px.

Answer (score 0):

Türkmüsün :D table a  width 100% ata telefondayım net olarak bakamıyorum şu an sonra döneceğim sana

.tabloSinifim {
Width:100%;}

Attribute olarakta atayabilirsin.

Comment: add absolute positioning and set the overflow property, use a class or inline styling to set precedence to these values.

Comment: İlla okutacaksınız yamukucam ekranda iyi bekleyin.

Comment: Sitilleri göremiyorum ama bir yerlerde clear unutmuş olabilirmisin acaba ? Ve modal fixed mı absolute mu acaba ? Diğer bir ihtimalde sitil çakışması olabilir çok acil değilse ve test adresin varsa gece 22:00 dan sonra bakabilirim